# Handling the signal generated by system reboot

Tags: c, linux, process

Whenever I give reboot command, my process is receiving SIGTERM signal and is handling it. I don't want to handle it if the SIGTERM is due to reboot.

Please suggest me any idea.

Is there any way to send `kill -9` signal to my process when I do `system("reboot")`?

I am using Cent OS (Linux).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> whenever i give reboot command,my process is receiving SIGTERM signal and is handling it. I dont want to handle it if the SIGTERM is due to reboot.

You may try to run `/sbin/runlevel` in your signal handler (well, maybe process spawning is not even possible in a signal handler though) to get the current runlevel. Runlevel 6 is reboot.

> Is there any way to send kill -9 signal to my process when i do system(reboot).

If your process is started by init scripts you can change the script so that stop is performed with `kill -KILL` instead of something else.

> I am using Cent OS(linux).

I don't know if the following applies for CentOS.

In Debian, all remaining processes (the ones alive after all kill scripts have been ran) are signaled by `/etc/init.d/sendsigs`. If you have administrator access you can try to customize it so a specially named process (yours) get KILLed without TERMing before.

Still, all pids related in `/run/sendsigs.omit` and all pids related in files in `/run/sendsigs.omit.d/` don't receive any signal.

Answer (score 0):

If your process is issuing the command to reboot the system, clearly it knows that the reboot is coming. Have it set up appropriate signal handlers beforehand, e.g.

```
signal(SIGTERM, SIG_IGN); // or SIG_DFL to restore default action (terminate process)
system("reboot");
```

Your process will still eventually get killed (via `SIGKILL`) right before the system halts, but that won't happen until a little later in the reboot process.

Comment: how can i handle if i run reboot in linux console.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my question above and just wanted to update here. 
In /etc/init.d there is a file "halt".
This halt is executed only on runlevel 0 and 6.
i added a line "pkill -9 processname" before it it sends SIGTERM to all the processes.